# Change anchor text

Tags: javascript, anchor, locale, translate

JS noob here trying to get the text of an anchor to switch out based on a variable set by the language selected.

Here is what I'm trying.

```
<a id="translate-button" href="#">english text</a>

var locale = "es";

if(locale == "es") {
   $('#translate-button').text("texto Español");
}
```

Comment: You have a typo , it should be `if(locale == "es")`

Comment: You have an error in your conditional.  it should be locale == 'es'

Comment: Cheers. I tried with both the quotes and not quotes, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What errors are you getting? You can check your browser console

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo A-ha, thanks. Didn't know what a browser console was or how to check for errors, but now I do. It is saying "locale" is not defined. Is it because it this variable is defined in the load script, where as the 'if statement' is in the footer?